# Google cloud function Golang unit test with init()

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am having problems creating a Cloud Function in Golang and creating unit tests for it. Specifically, the environment variables that I want to inject during the test phase are not recognized, since the init() function always runs before the test. This init() function uses the environment variables to create a client. Is there any way around this problem?

Google recommends putting global variables like clients in the init() function, to reuse those objects in future invocations. This reduces startup time ([source](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips)).

**Directory structure**

```
/function
  do_something.go
  do_something_test.go
```

**do_something.go**

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "os"

    "cloud.google.com/go/firestore"
)

var (
    projectID = os.Getenv("GCLOUD_PROJECT")
    client    *firestore.Client
)

func init() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    var err error
    client, err = firestore.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Firestore: %v", err)
    }
}

func Main(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Do something
}
```

**do_something_test.go**

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "testing"
)

func init() {
    os.Setenv("GCLOUD_PROJECT", "my-test-project") // This does not work because of lexigraphical order, init() in do_something.go before this init().
}

func TestMain(t *testing.T) {
    os.Setenv("GCLOUD_PROJECT", "my-test-project") // This does not work because init() is run before TestMain.
}
```

**Possible solutions**

1. Do not use init() in `do_something.go`. However, this gives a penalty in cloud function performance, latency is increased due to extended startup time.
2. Inject variables through a configuration file. However, I think this introduces the same problem.
3. Set environment variables before running `go test`. This is feasible, however I find this a suboptimal solution, since I don't want to run extra arguments before doing the actual test.
4. Always default to the development environment unless an environment variable specifies the code runs in production:

```
projectID = GetEnv("GCLOUD_PROJECT", "my-test-project")

func GetEnv(key string, defaultVal string) string {
    if value, exists := os.LookupEnv(key); exists {
        return value
    }
    return defaultVal
}
```

Comment: "so that they can be shared by different instances of the cloud function". That's incorrect. Globals can be reused by subsequent _invocations_ of the same instance of the cloud function, but there is no way different instances can share stuff.

Comment: What is `Main`? Is it your GCF's entrypoint? If so, why does its signature not match that of a `http.Handler`?

Comment: I updated my question with the correct entrypoint and changed the text about global variables.

Comment: @Nebulastic did you find a solution?

Comment: @Oooha, I ended up using only a single init function in my main code. That init function initializes clients and sets environment variables. The same clients can be reused in the tests. And the environment variables have default values (as in the OP).

Answer (score 1):

You should be exposing an environment variable at project level stating if the code is being executed in `test` settings or `prod` settings. Based on this, your `init` function will set the values of the variables.

Comment: Do you maybe have a code example that does exactly this?

Comment: Sadly i don't. I did resolve this issue in one of my project but i don't have access to that project anymore. do you have your codebase up somewhere? probably i can pull it and try to implement

Comment: Nope, not public. But you could easily create a main.go and main_test.go and use my snippets.